# Convex or not convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, convex-analysis

> Let $$ z(x) = x^H P^H_1 (cI + P_2 x x^H P^H_2 + P_3 x x^H P^H_3)^{-1} P_1 x $$ where $ c > 0 $, $ x \in \mathbb{C}^{N} $, and $ P_1, P_2, P_3 \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N} $. Is $z$ convex or not?

We can realize that the matrix $ (cI + P_2 x x^H P^H_2 + P_3 x x^H P^H_3) $ is positive definite. Thus, its inverse will also be positive definite. However, when considering the whole expression $ z(x) $, I am not sure if it is convex or not.

My attempt has been to compute the second derivative of $ z $. However, the first derivative is already quite complex and I doubt this will lead to my answer.

$$
\nabla_x z(x) = x^H P^H_1 Y^{-1} P_1 - ( x^H P^H_2 Y^{-1} P_1 x x^H P^H_1 Y^{-1} P_2 + x^H P^H_3 Y^{-1} P_1 x x^H P^H_1 Y^{-1} P_3 )
$$
where $ Y = (cI + P_2 x x^H P^H_2 + P_3 x x^H P^H_3) $

Any alternative way to prove convexity/non-convexity?

Comment: What are the variables ? What are the constants ?

Comment: The variable is the complex-valued vector $ x $

Comment: What is $x^H$ ?

Comment: you can not say that $z(x)$ is convex because $(cI + P_2 x x^H P^H_2 + P_3 x x^H P^H_3)$ is PD. This only works if $(cI + P_2 x x^H P^H_2 + P_3 x x^H P^H_3)$ is independent of $x$, i.e. the Hessian of the function is PD.

Comment: @GabrielRomon it is the conjugate transpose

Comment: Ahmad, it is not independent as you mention. However, it does not matter what value $ x $ takes because $  (cI + P_2 x x^H P^H_2 + P_3 x x^H P^H_3) $ will always be positive definite. Even if $ P_2 $ and $ P_3$ are singular, that will hold. I am honestly a bit confused.

Comment: I have plotted this function for two dimensions, and I get something similar to two ridge functions. Based on that, I will conclude that the function is not convex.